# Store EXEC Result into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
EXEC ('SELECT  ID,        
  Date,        
  Type,                                
  FROM DB2T.BBT') AT DB2
```

How do I store this into a table so that I can add results from another query to do it? I'm very new to sql and have done a lot of searching but it seems everything I find is specific to that scenario. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Based on the fact that you have already asked one or two questions on this exact topic it is obvious this is an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

You need `SELECT. . . INTO` :

```
SELECT ID, Date, Type INTO Table_name                             
FROM DB2T.BBT;
```

If you have already table then you can use `INSERT INTO` statement :

```
INSERT INTO Table_name (ID, Date, Type)
     SELECT  ID, Date, Type                     
     FROM DB2T.BBT;
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Invalid object name 'DB2T.BBT'". I think I need the "at DB2" at the end to make the query work

Comment: @tjc. . . `DB2T.BBT` is your object or table_name (`Schema.Table_name`), you have to ensure `DB2T.BBT` exists in your current database.

Comment: I was told that this exec statement is the only way to get the data that I want, is there no way to have that exec statement and then have something after that stores it somewhere?

Comment: @tjc, "Exec... At DB2' is allowing you to run dynamic sql on a linked server.  Place all of Yogesh's syntax in your exec statement, wrapped in single tics.

Comment: This answer is a poor one. There is a substantial difference between accessing the linked server through a `SELECT` and an `EXEC AT` and it can have major performance implications.